# "Reading and Writings" section in completeness score doesn't link well

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The hints behind the "Reading" and "Writing" list items link to `#reading` and `#writing` on my profile edit page.  After the redirect, the page scrolls correctly, but a moment later my answers load which then push the section I'm supposed to be linked to off the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only took nearly three years, but this has now been fixed. After your answers load, the window is now scrolled to the correct position, so you're where you expected to be.