# Bug in Careers ad with duplicated town name?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I see an ad in the right of the StackOverflow page with the following text:

> [image]

Text:

> Software Design Engineer
>
> Key Technology
>
> Walla, WA / remote / relocation

However, I'm pretty sure that *Key Technology* would have put in 'Walla Walla', not just 'Walla'.  Was the second 'Walla' removed because the software thought there was a duplication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spot-on. That's *exactly* what happened.

We clearly owe an apology to a few places: sorry, [Paw Paw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paw_Paw,_Michigan), [Ty Ty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ty_Ty,_Georgia), and [Walla Walla](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/49337), for  brutally discarding half of your names with a slightly imperfect regular expression!

In our defense, our complex and highly sophisticated location abbreviation and de-duplication system has worked well in the past for places such as "Singapore, Singapore" and "Hong Kong, Hong Kong". Also, we have yet to hear a single complaint from the mayors of [Hoohoo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoohoo,_Raleigh_County,_West_Virginia) and [Tumtum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tumtum,_Washington) - our classified algorithms are also handling those places correctly.

Comment: I hate to sound ungrateful or complaining when it is not my intention to do so, but am I correct in observing that it took a year for anybody to comment this in any way, even if the problem itself seems quite clear (at least in retrospect)? So if I open another similar issue, it make take an equal amount of time?

Comment: @eis year?? Looks like four days to me. (the 13 is the day in March, not year)

Comment: @ShadowWizard my bad :) So I was not correct, which is a good thing! Thanks for pointing it out for me.

Comment: @eis cheers, but I can't deny some bugs do lurk for years. [Example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106800/reading-and-writings-section-in-completeness-score-doesnt-link-well). (hint hint, `@Max` :))